# How to group repetitive items?

Tags: lookup-column

I have 1 list and 4 field in it.

one column is person,
one is title,
one is feature,
one is experience.

all columns are look up except title.

But i have problem with person. If i want to add multiple features, i must create that count item.

Is there any way to group persons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List --> list settings --> select the view --> go to "group by" section --> select the person field and save

Answer (score 0):

You can group by Name - First Name, Last Name or Full Name. Does that help?